# Sending an email with Go through AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

I wrote a lambda function in Go that would handle a form submission and send an email with the captured form data to a configured email address.

I am using AWS SES, or trying to.

My `emailService.go` has the following code:

```
package aj

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

var (
    host       = os.Getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
    username   = os.Getenv("EMAIL_USERNAME")
    password   = os.Getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
    portNumber = os.Getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
    from       = os.Getenv("SOURCE_EMAIL")
)

type EmailService struct {
    auth smtp.Auth
}

type EmailSender interface {
    SendEmail(logger *zap.Logger, ctx context.Context, m *Message) error
}

func NewEmailService() *EmailService {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", username, password, host)

    return &EmailService{auth}
}

func (s *EmailService) SendEmail(logger *zap.Logger, ctx context.Context, m *Message) error {
    return smtp.SendMail(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, portNumber), s.auth, from, m.To, m.ToBytes())
}

func NewMessage(s, b string) *Message {
    return &Message{Subject: s, Body: b, Attachments: make(map[string][]byte)}
}

func (m *Message) AttachFile(src string) error {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, fileName := filepath.Split(src)
    m.Attachments[fileName] = b
    return nil
}

func (m *Message) ToBytes() []byte {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    withAttachments := len(m.Attachments) > 0
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\n", m.Subject))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\n", strings.Join(m.To, ",")))
    if len(m.CC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Cc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.CC, ",")))
    }

    if len(m.BCC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Bcc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.BCC, ",")))
    }

    buf.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\n")
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
    boundary := writer.Boundary()
    if withAttachments {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s\n", boundary))
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))
    } else {
        buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n")
    }

    buf.WriteString(m.Body)
    if withAttachments {
        for k, v := range m.Attachments {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n\n--%s\n", boundary))
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: %s\n", http.DetectContentType(v)))
            buf.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n")
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s\n", k))

            b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(v)))
            base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b, v)
            buf.Write(b)
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s", boundary))
        }

        buf.WriteString("--")
    }

    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

As you can see, I am using the standard library `net/smtp` package. Is that Ok to do when you want to send an email through SES? Of course, I am passing my SES SMTP credentials for the necessary/required environment variables.

Right now, I'm not getting any errors, but I am **also not receiving emails** even though the count on "emails sent" on the SES Dashboard (within the AWS Console) increments each time I send a request to my lambda function.

[image: SES dashboard]

Am I going about this the wrong way? It is not working because I must use the SES package within the AWS SDK?

In the HTTP handler, I'm doing:

```
err = r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("error parsing form data", zap.Error(err))
    http.Error(w, "error parsing form data", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

I believe there's a limit of 10Mb on SES emails, and I believe the `10 << 20` ensure I don't go over? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: See [Troubleshooting Amazon SES issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot.html).

Comment: I think you should use AWS SDK to work with AWS services. AWS provides the sample code [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/ses-example-send-email.html)